# useref Cannot set property 'display' in a react comp

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hey I'm trying to make a basic React scroll to top button and I got this code from w3 and I think its good I tried to change some stuff but without success, I believe the solution is stupid hope for help thanks you. i get this error:

> Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

This is my code:

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const myButton = useRef(null);

  // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
  window.onscroll = function () {
    scrollFunction();
  };

  function scrollFunction() {
    if (
      document.body.scrollTop > 20 ||
      document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20
    ) {
      myButton.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      myButton.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
  function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onclick="topFunction()" ref={myButton} title="Go to top">
        Top
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ScrollToTop;
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be myButton.current.style.display.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you are using `useRef` need to add current after variable name followed property
It will work with `myButton.current.style.display`.
With button styling to fixed bottom it will work